# What happened when Alexander the Great overtook most of Afro-Eurasia?

Tags: alexander-the-great

What was the political and social hierarchies during the Macedonian empire and after its splitting into multiple states? What freedoms and rights were the people given?

EDIT: This is as specific as I can get it. Please leave a comment if you would prefer that I split this into two questions.

These aren't textbook questions, just me wanting a bit of intuition.

Please provide what you can.

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to History.SE.  You'll probably get better answers if you focus your question a little more. Also, what research have you already done? Only reason I ask is that you mention Rome and Carthage, but the Macedonian empire extended to the east, not the west.

Comment: Ah, I see... I thought I was mentioning generic cities that were part of the Alexandrian regime, but apparently I was a bit flawed. Anyway, I know a lot about Hellenistic culture and its consequent integration of the Macedonian empire. I know that Alexander the Great used intelligent military tactics to unify most of Afro-Eurasia and ruled with absolute power (but the peoples rights are still unclear). I know about the slave trade that overtook most of the Mediterranean. I also know about Zeno's Stoicism and its influence on uniting the empire. My main question will be revised.nomorecharacters

Comment: I'm going to vote to "close to edit" - I like the core question, but I think it needs some refinement to fit within the guidelines of the site.

Comment: @louiemcconnell, can you clarify what the most important question is? There are a lot of questions embedded there, and I think you'll be more successful if you focus on one.  How has wikipedia fallen short of your needs?

Comment: The successors granted land (klerouchoi) to hellens to fight in their phalanxes, later they began recruiting Galatians, Thracians and others as well. They where often settled in the newly founded cities. The Hetairoi where given estates to raise horses on and would be a social and military elite.

Comment: Many of them intermarried with the old Persian nobility. Many of the persian nobles kept some of their power as well but where generally less high regarded. This depends on the successor kingdom. The Ptolemaioi for example originally distrusted their egyptian subjects. After deploying 30000 of them in the battle of Raphia they revolted from their rule. Generally these kingdoms regarded Makedones the highest, but others could gain power through good service.